# Showing the existence of an automorphism $v$ such that $v=f$ in the supplement of $Ker(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of a vector space $E$ that has a finite dimension.
Let $F$ be a sub vector space of $E$ such that $E=F + Ker(f)$ is a direct sum, $Ker(f)$ is the kernel of $f$. 
Show that an automorphism $v$ of $E$ exists such that for all $x \in F$ : $v(x)=f(x)$. 
I found this exercice in the top of a lengthy problem of Ideals in linear algebra as a fundemental result to use in the following questions. Since we have mapped all elements of $F$, I have to map elements of the Kernel and assign them values such that $v$ is an ismorphism so I thought of assigning them to a sub vector space that is in direct sum with $Im(f)$ but I can't even verify linearity...other than that I'm quite stuck on this one. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Try showing that the restriction of $f$ to $F$ is injective.

Comment: I did show it but I am not sure how that will help, as I mentioned the problem is with assigning elements of the kernel, but yes $f* : F \rightarrow Im(f) $ is an isomorphism

Comment: Let $\beta=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ be an ordered basis of $E$ such that the first $m$ vectors of $\beta$ form a basis of $F$ and the last $n-m$ vectors of $\beta$ form a basis for $\ker(f)$. Note $$\{f(e_1),...,f(e_m)\}$$ forms a basis for $F^*=f(E)$. Erect this ordered basis of $F^*$ to another ordered basis $\beta^*$ of $E$ given by $$\{f(e_1),...,f(e_m),\alpha_{m+1},...,\alpha_n\}$$ Can you define $v$ from here?

Comment: OH I see it now, by assigning $v(e_i)= \alpha_i$ for $i \ge m $ I can define $v$ by defining the images of vectors of a basis in $E$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. The idea is to define $v$ so that the induced change of basis map which sends coordinates of $\beta$ to coordinates of $\beta^*$ is the identity on $ \mathbb{F}^n$. I always try to work with bases to see where that takes me. Just a nice problem solving trick :)